# Different types of methods to read JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to load JSON when the page is loading. I found two methods but what is the difference between following two methods to read JSON.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/json/mainpage.json"></script>
//code for what to do with this
```

another method is

```
$.getJSON("assets/json/mainpage.json")
```

Comment: The first is unlikely to work unless the server serves text/javascript and is cheating on the extension

Comment: With the first method there is no way to access the JSON from the code. The first method is no method.

Answer (score 0):

You did not find two different methods.

The first version is not how it works.

You can load a JavaScript object that is using object notation using a script tag, so

`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/json/mainpage.js"></script>`

could contain

```
var myJSObject = { "key":"value" };
```

whereas the second method will call something that returns (static or generated) content like

```
{ "key":"value" }
```

For example

```
$.getJSON("assets/json/mainpage.php");
```

would call a server process that would do

```
header("content-type: application/json");
echo '{ "key":"value" }';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `assets/json/mainpage.json` returns a pure JSON, the first method is totally wrong because the tag `<script>` is intended to serve some sort of scripting language, and a [JSON](http://json.org/) is not a scripting language. It's not impossible to see something like this method, though. If the `assets/json/mainpage.json` supports JSON padding, mainly knows as [JSONP](http://json-p.org/), the following snippet is completely valid:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/json/mainpage.json?callback=fn"></script>
```

You can keep the `.json` extension (or any extension you like) as long as the server returns the result as a `Content-Type: javascript/text` on the response header and wraps the result in the `callback` function. Note that the value of  the `callback` param must be a name of a function that is globally accessible.

The second method is the same as doing an ajax call to the JSON and parsing its content. This is the one you should use, between the two. Although it's kind of useless without a callback or promise for response.

```
$.getJSON("assets/json/mainpage.json").done(function(res) { /* handle response */ });
```

Hope it helps.